# Cannot resolve template using Jersey

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, jetty

I'm creating a simple webservice using Jersey. I want to return a JSP names home.jsp but always get the following error when using the `http://localhost:{port}/home` endpoint:

> The template name, /WebRoot/views/home.jsp, could not be resolved to a
>   fully qualified template name

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Project layout:**

```
-src/main/java
   -resource
       -jsp
         -HomeResource.java
       -rest
         -HomeRestResource.java (Note rest endpoints are working fine)
-WebRoot
   -views
      -home.jsp
   -WEB-INF
      -web.xml
```

**HomeResource.java**

```
@Path("/home")
public class HomeResource{

    private final static String RESOURCE_PATH = "/WebRoot/views/home.jsp";

    @GET
    public Viewable getView() {
        return new Viewable(RESOURCE_PATH);
    }
}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Service</h1>
</body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>resource</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath
            </param-name>
            <param-value>/WebRoot/views</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex
            </param-name>
            <param-value>/(images|js|styles|(WebRoot/views))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

**Other Notes**

I'm using a Jetty server to run this web app

Comment: Is `WebRoot` a folder you created yourself?

Comment: @peeskillet It may be the result of a gradle plugin, I don't think it's necessary really

Comment: If you didn't create it, I'm going to guess it is not built at part of the app. Most IDEs have a root folder view in the project explorer (but it's not part of the app). Maybe that's what you are seeing. I would try to get rid of it in the path, and see what happens

Comment: @peeskillet That seems to work! I wonder why...

Comment: I explained in the comment why. WebRoot is not a real folder

Comment: @peeskillet If I go into the project directory in windows file explorer there is a WebRoot folder though

Comment: I've never used gradle for a webapp before. Maven uses a different structure. It has a `webapp` folder that is not included into the build. I guess that's what gradle does. But where you should be looking is in the actual `.war` file. That' where you'll find your answer. Either find the exploded war in the server, or explode it yourself. You will most likely see the `WebRoot` folder is not there

Answer (score 0):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath
    </param-name>
    <param-value>/WebRoot/views</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Here you're telling Jersey to prepend `/WebRoot/views` to your JSP path.

```
private final static String RESOURCE_PATH = "/WebRoot/views/home.jsp";
```

Here you're saying that the JSP path is `/WebRoot/views/home.jsp`.

So Jersey is probably looking for `/WebRoot/views/WebRoot/views/home.jsp` and not finding it.

I suggest removing that `init-param` or at least setting the value to `/` instead of `/WebRoot/views`.